# multiplying a matrix and a vector, logic error

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a function , which is to mulitply a matrix and vector:

```
 double *matrix_vector_multiply(int rows, int cols,
                           double **mat, double *vec)
{

    double *answer = malloc(rows * sizeof (double));
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<rows; rows++)
    ans[i]=0;

    for (i=0; i<rows; rows++){

        for (j=0; j<cols; cols++)
             {
            answer[i] = answer[i] + mat[i][j] * vec[j];
            }
        }
    return ans;
}
```

I keep getting all 0's for the output.. any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: (i) for your own good, get used to the idiom `sizeof( *answer )` rather than `sizeof( double )`; (ii) post an example we can run and test. (iii) `ans`, which you return and initialize, is nowhere declared; instead, you declare and modify `answer`. (iv) Each loop iteration, you increase `rows` and `cols`, but your indices are `i` and `j`; how come these loops ever end?

Comment: why are you increasing the number of rows and cols in your for loops rather than increasing i and j?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you asking a new question that basically turns arround the same problems? Please read up about basic C first, before you ask questions about such things. And please don't start programming C by using an emulation of a 2D array. You have pointers to pointers, these are different things. At least start with simpler things, learn how to properly use a `for` loop and things like that, passing through SO for such things is just a waste of time for everybody, you including.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this actual code that you have posted ? As well as the obvious problems with `ans` and `answer` etc, your for loops are completely wrong, e.g.

```
for (i=0; i<rows; rows++)
```

should be:

```
for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
```

and:

```
    for (j=0; j<cols; cols++)
```

should be:

```
    for (j=0; j<cols; j++)
```

Comment: I doubt that the OP posted original code, since the loop `(i=0; i < rows; rows++)` would never end, unless `rows == 0`.

Comment: Well it would end eventually, when rows increments beyond INT_MAX. But the code doesn't compile anyway, unless perhaps `ans` is declared as a global somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have `ans` and `answer`. I hope you can figure out the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

The variables i and j in your two for loops never change since you seem to increase rows and cols instead.  This means that you would always do the same sum in the body of the second for loop.  Your other answers have no choice but to stay at 0 because you never calculate their values after init.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all values as 0 in `ans` and then returning `ans`. Whereas you are clearly modifying variable `answer` .